# Get all classes from a namespace that implements certain interface using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, class, interface, namespaces

I have multiple classes in a namespace implementing certain interface, and I want to make a list of all classes, that match the same interface.

Is there a way to reach that using `System.Reflection`?

```
public interface A
{}
public class AB : A
{}
public class AC : A
{}
public class AD : A
{}

List<A> classList = { AB, AC, AD};
```

Thanks.

Comment: how is is this duplicate if he asks about the namespaces and the question is answering about assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
            var interfaceType = typeof(A);
            var classes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom).ToList();
            classes.Remove(typeof(A));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to know which assembly the types are in. Then get the types from that assembly, and find the ones that implement your interface.

```
Assembly a = typeof(A).Assembly;
var list = a.GetTypes().Where(type => type != typeof(A) && typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, see Type.implementsInterface for more information. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383789(v=vs.100).aspx

You can also use typeof(IWhateverable).IsAssignableFrom(myType)

More information from here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx